# Facing issues while installing Tensorflow behind a proxy

Tags: installation, conda, http-proxy

I am currently using Python (Version: `3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)|`). While i am trying to install tensorflow , it is throwing an error. I don't understand how to solve. Below is the error:

```
Collecting tensorflow
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel 
connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': 
/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel 
connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': 
/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel 
connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': 
/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel 
connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': 
/simple/tensorflow/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel 
connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': 
/simple/tensorflow/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
```

I don't have any internet connection problem. Could anyone please help me regarding this.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy did you also configure a proxy for conda like https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/index.html

Comment: @tardis.. Yes i did

Comment: Looks like you forgot to configure username and pw for the proxy? at least the error `Proxy Authentication Required` seems to indicate that

Comment: @FlyingTeller..i am getting an error now "Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
ProxyError: Proxy error: Could not find a proxy for 'https'. See
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/html#configure-conda-for-use-behind-a-proxy-server
for more information on how to configure proxies." . Actually i am completely new to this, could you please guide me what to do now ??

Comment: You have to give more info. Are you behind a proxy? Do you have configured a proxy for conda/anaconda both via http and https (not a proxy for the os or webbrowser)? If yes, how?

Comment: @tardis..Yea i am behind a proxy.. I have not configured a proxy for conda/anaconda via hhtp& https.  Kindly guide me how to do ..

Answer (score 0):

To install tensorflow behind a proxy follow the below steps

**Step 1:** Setting environment variables

HTTP_PROXY = http://user:password@proxy:portnumber

HTTPS_PROXY = https://user:password@proxy:portnumber

**Step 2:** Setting proxy servers in .condarc file.

In ".condarc" file which will be in /Users/username/.condarc, add the below lines

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http://user:password@proxy:portnumber
  https: https://user:password@proxy:portnumber
```

**Step 3:** Install through Anaconda (conda prompt)

**Method 1:**

Open conda prompt, create new environment for installation through the below commands

```
conda create -n tensorflow
activate tensorflow
conda install jupyter
conda install scipy
conda install tensorflow
```

**Method 2:**

Download the below listed files:

1. tensorflow jar with name win-64/tensorflow-1.3.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 from [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files?page=2)
2. protobuf jar with name win-64/protobuf-3.2.0-py36_0.tar.bz2 from [link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/protobuf/files?page=3)
3. repodata.json.bz2 from [link](https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/repodata.json.bz2)

Now in conda prompt, move to the downloaded directory and give these commands

```
conda install tensorflow-1.3.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
conda install protobuf-3.2.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
```

Now you are all set either by method 1 or method 2.

To check the installation from conda prompt itself, give these commands

```
python ####this will open python workspace from conda
import tensorflow as tf ####if running this didnt gave any error u r all set
```

**NOTE:**
If any of the conda commands didn't work(as you are under proxy), give these commands:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
set NO_PROXY=continuum.io,anaconda.org
```

Hope this helps :)